# iOS - Open PHP url in uiwebview from IBAction

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have this code inside a IBAction:

```
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.brmyapps.com/folder/folder/registerpost.php?first_name=%@&last_name=%@&titulo_noticia=%@&comments=%@&idpub=%@&dataevento=%@&email=%@", self.textnome.text, self.textimg.text, self.texttitulo.text, self.textnoticia.text, self.textid.text, self.textdata.text, self.textemail.text];

self.aWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];

self.aWebView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
self.aWebView.autoresizingMask=(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth);

[self.aWebView setDelegate:self];
NSString *urlAddress = strURL; // test view is working with url to webpage


NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[self.aWebView loadRequest:requestObj];

UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
[[self view] addSubview:_aWebView];
```

My Problem is that when I click in the button, opens UIWebView but the php url i want to open to send data to php is not loading. Only a blank page is showed.

How can i solve this?

Comment: Unless you suspect there's an error in the PHP code, I don't see why you tagged PHP.

Comment: Load the request after setting up the web view, not before. And what's the point of the `view` variable and the zero frame `UIView` you create?

Comment: Also make sure none of the values used to build the URL have any spaces. If they do, you need to properly escape them.

Comment: My php is working correctly with html form. And i created a view with size equal 0 because i dont want to display it... I just want to send data from xcode form to php and save into database... I'll try to load the request after create a webview

Comment: I got the problem. My problem is the space. I can't write anything with space. If I write any space text i got a error; How can i solve this? Any suggestion?

Comment: I solved my problem replacing the whitespace to _ and now it's working. But now i have another problem. My app has many UIControllerViews and when i change the page all data saved in db is cleaned. How can i stop this?

Comment: I solved the problem. It was my php code that was cleaning the db. Thanks to all for help...